# Get javascript object types as console.log outputs in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to introspect some objects to know their type. In particular, I need to identify `functions` and `async functions`. For example consider the following object:

```
f = function(){}
af = async function(){}
class c {}
```

Using `typeof` won't work because for any of these objects, the type is `function`

```
> typeof f
'function'
> typeof af
'function'
> typeof c
'function'
```

This improves a little if I use `Object.prototype.toString.call()` on each object:

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call(f)
'[object Function]'
>Object.prototype.toString.call(af)
'[object AsyncFunction]'
>Object.prototype.toString.call(c)
'[object Function]'
```

I still, cannot differentiate a function from a class. However, `console.log` is able to do it:

```
> console.log(f)
[Function: f]
> console.log(af)
[AsyncFunction: af]
> console.log(c)
[class c]
```

So my question is, how can I mimic what `console.log` is doing to identify the correct type of a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `util` module of Node.js, for instance the [`inspect` function](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options).

**Note:** You need to import it `const util = require("util")`. It's not a global object!

```js
> class A {}
> util.inspect(A)
'[class A]'
> f = () => {}
> af = async () => {}
> util.inspect(f)
'[Function: f]'
> util.inspect(af)
'[AsyncFunction: af]'
```